# Can someone help me design a circuit that will open when power is applied and close after power is removed?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, solenoid

I am using an air conditioner thermostat transformer which provides power to my circuit. When the thermostat powers up, the door opens. I want the door to remain open until the thermostat shuts off, then I want the door to close. I'm using a solenoid to operate the door. The Transformer is 24 volts reduced to 6 volts. How can I keep the door open as long as the thermostat is operating then close once the thermostat ceases? I have exhausted my knowledge base and hope help may be found here. Thank you for examining this project. -Kegbuster

Comment: Your post says that the door opens when the thermostat contacts close ("powers up"?). So that requirement is met. When the thermostat contacts open power is removed so that should cause the door to close. It is not clear from your question what the problem is. Please edit the question (use the "edit" link) to clarify.

Comment: SPDT relays permit you to choose Normally open(NO) when inactive or normally closed (NC) for inverted logic controlled power.

Comment: it is unclear what kind of a thermostat you have .... you say that it powers up .... does that mean that it outputs a voltage? ..... or is it just a switch that closes a circuit (it does not actually produce a voltage)?

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVXVeZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A thermostat-controlled solenoid.*

What you are describing in your question could be solved with the simple circit of Figure 1.

How it works:

- When the thermostat threshold is exceeded the T'STAT contact closes and 6 V is applied to the solenoid. Your door should open.
- When the temperature drops below the threshold the T'STAT contact opens again, power is removed from the solenoid and your door should close.

This seems so trivial that I suspect there is some complication that hasn't been explained in your question. If you clarify your question we can address the problem more appropriately.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments and assistance. I apologize for my lack of knowledge and terminology. I believe Transistor has answered my question. Thanks again!

Comment: @Kegbuster feel free to accept it then

Comment: @Keg: Try it out. If you need further assistance then update your question. If it works then you can accept this answer using the link on the left.